# Django race conditions between create() and get()

Tags: django, postgresql, rq

Since our last release a range of what seems can only DB race conditions have been happening.We use python 3.10, django-rq, Django 4 and Postgres.

In one case:

```
x = Model.objects.create()
job.delay(x_id=x.id)
```

In the job we call Model.objects.get(id=x.id)
and it raises 'matching query does not exist.' error. This is happening roughly 1 in 5 times from logs

In another case we create the object, add it to a list then act on the list and again it works most of the time but we are getting one off 'matching query does not exist.' errors.

I am completely stumped as to what I should do, I cant find many similar issues and can't recreate the issues in my test environment.

My best assumption is too many writes to the DB so the transactions aren't being committed by the time the code tries to get the objects again.

Any help/advice would be amazing

- Have gone through the code step by step to ensure the logic is sound
- Have tried recreating a 'busy' DB but have had no success there
- Have tried broken data etc but it all gets caught and our logs don't suggest anything like this either

Comment: "`get()` (...) returns nothing" sounds very strange - it should either return instance or raise exception. What kind of "nothing" is it when you print/log it - `None`?

Comment: maybe try passing just `model.id` instead of the whole instance to the job?

Comment: edited for the above as it raises an error and we do pass the id

Answer (score 1):

In this case a job to `get` object should be scheduled after `create` is committed to database.

This can be done using on_commit hook https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/transactions/#performing-actions-after-commit

Example:

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.atomic
def your_method():
    x = Model.objects.create()
        
    transaction.on_commit(job.delay(x_id=x.id))
```

Comment: this looks like it has potential, ill look into it thankyou